# How do I show two different definitions for an exterior point are equivalent?

Tags: general-topology

I have to show that the following two statements are equivalent.  The first is the definition I was given by my professor for an exterior point.  The second is the definition out of our textbook.

How do I show that they are equivalent? Does this require a proof?

Let $(X, \mathfrak T)$ be a topological space and let $ A \subseteq X$ and let $x$ be an element in $X$.

1. $x \notin A$ and $x \notin Bd(A)$
2. There is an open set $U$ such that $x \in U \subseteq X-A.$

For the first one if I let $ x \in X$ then I would also have to say X is an open set and then $ x\notin Bd(A)$ I guess here if $ x \in X$ then $ x \notin X-A$ but I don't know if I can say that?

For the second definition again letting $x \in X $ then $x \in X-A$ but I am not sure how to show that $ U \subseteq X-A$

Answer (score 1):

I recall that $Bd(A)=\overline{A}\cap \overline{X-A}$.

$1 \Rightarrow 2$. Since $x\not\in A$, $x\in X-A$. Assume that there is no open set $U$ such that $x \in U \subseteq X-A$. Then $x\in\overline A$. Then 
$x\in (X-A)\cap \overline A\subseteq Bd(A)$, a contradiction,

$2 \Rightarrow 1$. We have $x\not\in\overline{A}$. So both $x\not\in A$ and $x\not\in Bd(A)$.